# table объединить ячейки

Tags: html, css, css3

1. Как сделать где 3 строка 1 ячейка цифры 5 и 130

```html
 <p style='color: blue'>Информация о выборе модулей ОРКСЭ на 2019-2020 уч. г.</p>
 <table style='border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse'>
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="2" align='center' style='border: 1px solid black; font-weight: bold'>плановое кол-во 4-х классов/ в них уч-ся в 2018-2019 у.г.</td>
   <td colspan='2' align='center' style='border: 1px solid black; font-weight: bold'>проведено родительских собраний по выбору модулей</td>
   <td colspan='6' align='center' style='border: 1px solid black; font-weight: bold'>количество обучающихся, выбравших млоули</td>
   <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>Обеспеченность учебниками</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <!-- <td>0</td> -->
   <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>кол-во собраний/кол-во присуствующих родителей</td>
   <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>кол-во представитей конфессий</td>
   <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>Основы мировых религиозных культур</td>
   <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>Основы светской этики</td>
   <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>Основы православной культуры</td>
   <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>Основы иудейской культуры</td>
   <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>Основы буддийской культуры</td>
   <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>Основы исламской культуры</td>
   <td align='center' style='color: blue; border: 1px solid black' >Родителькое собрание по выбору модулей ОРКСЭ проведено 28.02.2019г.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style='border: 1px solid black; padding: 0;'>
    <ul style='display: flex; list-style: none; justify-content: center; padding-left: 0; margin: 0;'>
     <li>5</li>
     <li>130</li>
    </ul>
   </td>
   <!-- <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>130</td> -->
   <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>5/115</td>
   <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>1</td>
   <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>0</td>
   <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>49</td>
   <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>81</td>
   <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>-</td>
   <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>-</td>
   <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>-</td>
   <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black;'>ОСЭ - 100% <br>
   ОПК - 100%</td>
   <!-- <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>О</td> -->
  </tr>
 </table>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<p style='color: blue'>Информация о выборе модулей ОРКСЭ на 2019-2020 уч. г.</p>
<table style='border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse'>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='2' rowspan="2" align='center' style='border: 1px solid black; font-weight: bold'>плановое кол-во 4-х классов/ в них уч-ся в 2018-2019 у.г.</td>
    <td colspan='2' align='center' style='border: 1px solid black; font-weight: bold'>проведено родительских собраний по выбору модулей</td>
    <td colspan='6' align='center' style='border: 1px solid black; font-weight: bold'>количество обучающихся, выбравших млоули</td>
    <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>Обеспеченность учебниками</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>кол-во собраний/кол-во присуствующих родителей</td>
    <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>кол-во представитей конфессий</td>
    <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>Основы мировых религиозных культур</td>
    <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>Основы светской этики</td>
    <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>Основы православной культуры</td>
    <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>Основы иудейской культуры</td>
    <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>Основы буддийской культуры</td>
    <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>Основы исламской культуры</td>
    <td align='center' style='color: blue; border: 1px solid black'>Родителькое собрание по выбору модулей ОРКСЭ проведено 28.02.2019г.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>5</td>
    <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>130</td>
    <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>5/115</td>
    <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>1</td>
    <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>0</td>
    <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>49</td>
    <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>81</td>
    <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>-</td>
    <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>-</td>
    <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black'>-</td>
    <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid black;'>ОСЭ - 100% <br> ОПК - 100%</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ячейки с цифрами 5 и 115 должна быть одна а не две

Comment: @Leks: Переделал.